# Powershell script not working for attachment

Tags: powershell, email, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, email-attachments

```
$EmailFrom = "xx@gmail.com"

$EmailTo = "yy.com"

$Subject = "Testing, Testing 123"

$Body = "this is a notification from XYZ Notifications.."

$Attachment = "C:\Users\XX\Desktop\Importanttxts\old.txt"

$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"

$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)

$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true

$SMTPClient.CredentialsObjectSystem.Net.NetworkCredential("pm8566","123456");

$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $Attachment)

cmd /c pause | out-null
```

This is my powershell script, it works fine, but without attachment, unable to send attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$smtpFrom = "xx@gmail.com"
$smtpTo = "yy.com"

$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"

$SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $smtpfrom, $smtpto

$SMTPClient.Subject = "Testing, Testing 123"

$SMTPClient.Attachments = "C:\Users\XX\Desktop\Importanttxts\old.txt"

$SMTPClient.Body = "this is a notification from XYZ Notifications.."

$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true

$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer)

$smtp.CredentialsObjectSystem.Net.NetworkCredential("pm8566","123456");

$smtp.Send($SMTPClient)

cmd /c pause | out-null
```

Comment: Not Working Bro, displaying message that attachment have read only property

Comment: does your file have access permission? Try giving everyone permission to the file.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell v3 has a built-in cmdlet for mail use case. Send-MailMessage.

[Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-6)

Any reason you choose to use .Net vs the cmdlet?

You can use the cmdlet with Gmail.
[PowerShell: Sending Email With Send-MailMessage (Gmail example)](https://www.pdq.com/blog/powershell-send-mailmessage-gmail)

```
$From = "YourEmail@gmail.com"
$To = "AnotherEmail@YourDomain.com"
$Cc = "YourBoss@YourDomain.com"
$Attachment = "C:\temp\Some random file.txt"
$Subject = "Email Subject"
$Body = "Insert body text here"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Cc $Cc -Subject $Subject `
-Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl `
-Credential (Get-Credential) -Attachments $Attachment
```

[#PSTip Sending emails using your Gmail account](https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/10/25/pstip-sending-emails-using-your-gmail-account/)

```
$param = @{
    SmtpServer = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    Port = 587
    UseSsl = $true
    Credential  = 'you@gmail.com'
    From = 'you@gmail.com'
    To = 'someone@somewhere.com'
    Subject = 'Sending emails through Gmail with Send-MailMessage'
    Body = "Check out the PowerShellMagazine.com website!"
    Attachments = 'D:\articles.csv'
}

Send-MailMessage @param
```

Comment: Bro i am using powershell v 1.0 :-(

Comment: OMG!!!!!! I guess your org is not really a risk management focused bunch.   ;-}  I showed the v3 way, because that was in your tags. Since you are stuck with v1, pull those other versions out of the tags, so all will know your pain.  :-{ and not make assumptions. So, back to what rAJ said.